# Database design for roles for members of organisations

Tags: database-design

I'm developing an IDP providing the same REST-api for a number of organisations. Each user is a member of at least one organisation and it is based on OAuth2 and OpenID Connect.

Every user of every organisation is either an admin or a regular member, but more roles may be added in the future.

After some research I've come to the conclusion that there are two ways in which I can solve this. Both implies that there are some kind of policy-service that authorizes each request, such as [OPA](https://www.openpolicyagent.org).

**Solution 1, global roles**
Every user should have a role in each organisation of which he/she is a member, but there will also be global endpoints such as `POST /orgs` which will create a new organisation. These endpoints should not be available to anyone but myself in this point in time. Therefore I need to create roles that are independent of organisations, see the `SYSTEM` resource type in the `role`-table.

However, this will require me to either skip the `org_membership` table completely and rely solely on roles when it comes to list members of the organisations or keep `org_membership` and `role` synchronized.

[image]

**Solution 2, organisational roles**
The second solution is to skip the `role`-table altogether and instead add the role-field to the `org_membership` table. This ensures that every member has a role but now I have to find another way to authorize against system-wide endpoints.

[image]

**Which would be the preferred solution for my case or is there anything else I should consider?**